# JavaScript function variable string digits geting cast into a Number?

Tags: javascript

i have a button that send a string of a phone number to func and try to call it
the problem i think is the func cast it in to a Number(not 100% sure )
and the string number start with 0543....
and when its trying to call it remove the 0 from the start
make sens if it was a Numberbut i need that 0 :)
how do i stop the casting to int

button that call:

```
<button onclick="callw(0544536421)"...
```

script: (alert for testing)

```
function callw(num){
            window.alert(num);  <---out put is 544536421 not 054...
            window.location.href="tel:"+num;
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your parameter in quotes `''`

```
  <button onclick="callw('0544536421')"
```

Comment: Better still don't inline Javascript in HTML and you would have likely noticed.

Comment: @Xotic750, Yep I have noticed

Comment: thx i am an idot i did try that but it didnt work i think added the '' to the second button and testing the first one so silly

Comment: @Satpal Lol, I know you did. :)

Comment: @user1246950, You don't need to feel like that everyone have one of these days